# Does Sqlite support transaction try/catch like SQL Server?

Tags: sqlite

Assume I have the following query in SQL Server:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [trans1]
 BEGIN TRY
  INSERT ...
  COMMIT TRANSACTION [trans1]
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [trans1]
 END CATCH
```

Does Sqlite support anything similar where I can embed the ROLLBACK directly into a transaction catch block?